# I am trying to trigger Alt tab Widget with SPACE + A

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I am trying to trigger Alt tab Widget with SPACE + A
but while holding down SPACE key, A and D need to act as directional keys. 
and lastly exit the Widget when SPACE is released.

The problem I am having is that when I release the SPACE key 
the widget does not disapear (alt remains stuck down)

I know I can invoke the sticky app switcher but this is more of 
an excersise to understand if/while GetKeyState, so please dont just 
reccomend alt+ctrl+tab

Thanks,

Here is my code.

```
Space & a::

Send,{Alt Down}
Send,{Tab}
Sleep, 200
While GetKeyState("Space", "P")

{
    a::Left 
    d::Right
}

If !GetKeyState("Space", "P")

{
    Send,{Alt Up}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Space & a::
    Send,{Alt Down}{Tab}
    ; Sleep, 200
Return

#If GetKeyState("Space", "P")

    a::Left 
    d::Right

    ; The tilde prefix (~) prevents AHK from blocking the key-down/up events:
    ~Space up:: Send,{Alt Up}

#If
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde

Comment: Sweet! that did it. Thanks! you are my hero